Why does my host app receive a 404 from my client app?
I'm trying to create a micro-frontend service using Vue, Vite, and vite-plugin-federation.
Host app vite.config.js:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import VueDevTools from 'vite-plugin-vue-devtools'
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";

const env = loadEnv( process.env.NODE_ENV, process.cwd() )

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    VueDevTools(),
    federation({
      name: 'host-app',
      remotes: {
          template_app: env.VITE_APP_URL+"/assets/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      shared: ['vue', "pinia", "vue-router"]
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: env.VITE_SHELL_PORT,
  }
})

Client vite.config.js:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";

const env = loadEnv( process.env.NODE_ENV, process.cwd() )

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    federation({
      name: 'template_app',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      // Modules to expose
      exposes: {
          './App': './src/views/AppView.vue',
      },
      shared: ['vue', "pinia", "vue-router"]
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: env.VITE_APP_PORT,
  },
  build: {
    minify: false,
    target: ["chrome89", "edge89", "firefox89", "safari15"]
 }
})

I'm bringing up the servers using "dev": "vite"
When the host calls the client it gets back a 404:
GET http://localhost:3031/assets/remoteEntry.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

But when I visit that url directly either through a browser or Postman I get a 200 and works well.
Why would the app not be able to call the same url the browser brings back successfully?

Are you sure they're both http://localhost:3031 and not, say, http:// vs https://?

Yes: http://localhost:3010/ and http://localhost:3031/ are the host and client respectively. Both display in the browser just fine.

http://localhost:3010/ and  http://localhost:3031/ Looks like the prefix didn't make it through to the previous comment

@emachine The comment above refers to that it's not obvious which protocol you use when open localhost:3031 in address bar, it's not shown. You need to check network tab for both cases, the difference between them should be evident there

@EstusFlask Yeah, I understand. Everything is http. One thing I didn't mention that may be relevant is that I'm using the vite command to bring up the servers.

Please post the details from network tab for both cases. Failed request details with headers and "status" column in a waterfall are of some interest. I'm not sure what happens here. ERR_ABORTED suggests the case is special and not just regular 404. Probably specific to module federation. This didn't occur to me

Read the Note at https://github.com/originjs/vite-plugin-federation?tab=readme-ov-file#vite-dev-mode - I think that's the issue ... maybe - i.e. you state that you bring up BOTH sides in dev mode

@JaromandaX I didn't really understand that at first but after thinking it over for a bit I tried vite preview and it finds the file now. Fantastic! This makes sense for the end product but unless I'm missing something it has a pretty dramatic negative impact on the development experience.

it's a failing  of the plugin I guess
